# Why is /sys not mounted in docker

Tags: docker

I'm trying to create a docker container and mount a my host `/sys/firmware` inside it. Referring to the documentation, I've tried both `-v` and `--mount` options. None of them worked. My container is `l4t` by NVIDIA, which is greatly modified Ubuntu 18.04, if I'm not mistaken. Below is the image of what I tried and what I got:

[image: My attempts]

The same issue occured for me, when trying to reproduce with `ubuntu:latest`

**UPD:** I found, that this could be done using `--privileged`, which I will stop on for now, but I would like to understand why is it impossible to do without this flag. Or how to do it without this flag

Comment: Docker is designed as an isolation system, and the general assumption is that containers shouldn't be allowed to modify host-global things.  Can you run the process directly on the host if it needs this level of hardware access?

Comment: @DavidMaze, Ok, I understand about isolation. But why can't it be mounted in, at least, read-only mode? I can run this on the host machine, but my final purpose is to run GitLab CI runner in that container. Having a CI runner outside of a container, I can't guarantee a clean build environment from run to run. That's why I want to Dockerize it.

Comment: Have found the same issue. There's something special about `/sys/firmware/`. The rest of the directories in `/sys` mount just fine. Alas, it's `/sys/firmware/` that's required for things like the `/proc/device-tree/system/linux,revision` and `/proc/device-tree/system/linux,serial` symlinks, which are commonly used to check what device the software is running on. Hardly a "level of hardware access".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out access to `/sys/firmware` has been [deliberately prohibited](https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/26618). From the PR:

> Some firmware information including SMBIOS and ACPI tables were unexpectedly exposed.
> Basically they shouldn't contain sensitive information, but some exceptions:

And these two examples are provided:

- `/sys/firmware/acpi/tables/{SLIC,MSDM}`: Windows license information
- `/sys/firmware/ibft/target0/chap-secret`: iSCSI CHAP secret

So the whole `/sys/firmware` tree has marked inaccessible using apparmor.

Given that 64-bit kernels now use this tree for key files like:

- `/sys/firmware/devicetree/base/serial-number`
- `/sys/firmware/devicetree/base/model`
- `/sys/firmware/devicetree/base/system/linux,revision`
- `/sys/firmware/devicetree/base/system/linux,serial`

which are symlinked under `/proc/device-tree`, I believe this is no longer a good idea. I've raised an [issue](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/43419).